# Use auto layout to have width of any view to be equal to the screen width

Tags: ios, autolayout

How can I make a view to have the width of the screen view. In Xcode 6 the default "Inferred" simulated metrics for the size is 600x600. When I add the constraints for the view to have the width of the view to be equal to the width of the parent, it keeps the size 600px because I am guessing that it takes the size of the simulated metrics....

How can I have the width to be equal to the screen width? Using "Width Equal" is obviously not an option here. So, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you set trailing and leading spacing to zero?

Comment: It puts the height of the object to zero; the view's height is flexible; it changes based on the content, so I don't know how to do it

Comment: OK I finally understood it after two days of playing with it.

Comment: So what was your solution?

Comment: I reconstructed the entire layout to have constraints between objects not superview. And doing that actually helped me with my alignment - I got rid of 50 lines of code because of that. And sizeToFit worked perfectly with the constraints also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any other constraints associated with width and set the leading & trailing to 0.